# Why does the script for installing nodejs 6_x installs 8_10?

Tags: apt, nodejs

I use the script from the official site to install nodejs 6_x:

```
wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

and see this output:

> Run sudo apt-get install -y nodejs to install Node.js 6.x LTS Boron
>   and npm

Why do I get nodejs **8_10** instead?

```
root@ip-172-31-42-193:/home/ubuntu# nodejs --version
v8.10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that Ubuntu 18.04 already has nodejs 8_10 in its apt repository.

```
root@ip-172-31-18-129:/home/ubuntu# apt-cache policy nodejs
nodejs:
  Installed: 6.14.1-1nodesource1
  Candidate: 8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.3
  Version table:
     8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.3 500
        500 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.2 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages
     8.10.0~dfsg-2 500
        500 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
 *** 6.14.1-1nodesource1 500
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I installed the specific version I wanted by:

```
apt-get install nodejs=6.14.1-1nodesource1
```